# LINQ's ToDictionary method and the order of its elements

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary

I have an `IEnumerable` of objects which I need to turn into a filtered dictionary. The key of the dictionary must be the object's name and the value must be one of its properties. I do so using LINQ's `ToString` method:

```cs
// dataPoints is of type IEnumerable
var filteredDictionary = dataPoints.Where(d => d.TypeName == typeNameOfInterest).ToDictionary(d => d.Name, d => d.Identifier)
```

I eventually turn the dictionary into a string as follows:

```cs
string.Join(Environment.NewLine, filteredDictionary.Select(d => $"{d.Key} : {d.Value};").ToArray()))
```

This works and the order of the elements in the string is the same as the order in the `IEnumerable`. I *think* that is what the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netframework-4.7.2) means by stating the following about the returned dictionary

> The values within each group are in the same order as in source

Now, I need to get the first element from the dictionary. By first I mean the first one listed in the original `IEnumerable`. How would I need to do this? Can I rely on LINQ's `first` method to do so and be sure that it is the correct one? Would I need to construct a `SortedDictionary` before getting the first element?

I'm using the .NET Framework 4.7.2 and I never modify the content of the dictionary that I receive from `ToDictionary`.

Comment: Dictionary items don't have an order. The fact that you're enumerating them in the same order as the source sequence is purely coincidence. Once your data set exceeds a certain size, that will change. Do you really need a dictionary? Or would a list of tuples of `typeNameOfInterest` and `Identifier` be sufficient? Based on the usage you've shown, it looks like it would, and you could use `First` on that with confidence.

Comment: Note that a `SortedDictionary` will sort elements according to the key rather than keeping them in the source order. It's not an "ordered dictionary", which would retain the order added and can be thought of as an indexed list.

Comment: Those are good comments, @madreflection. I don't *really* need a dictionary. It's eventually just used to build the string and get the first element.

Comment: I'm using `ToDictionary` because it is convenient to transform the `IEnumerable` using LINQ

Comment: Using `Select` to project a tuple is pretty easy: `dataPoints.Where(d => d.TypeName == typeNameOfInterest).Select(d => (d.Name,  d.Identifier)).ToList()`  Your `string.Join` call would be the same except for Name and Identifier instead of Key and Value. And like I said initially, you can use `First` with confidence on that.

Comment: @madreflection A naïve test seems to indicate that the documentation is correct - e.g. `Dictionary<>.Keys` remains in source order for 1 million integers or strings.

Comment: @ackh For what it's worth more than a year later, that wording in the documentation seems to have been lifted from the docs for [`ToLookup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup?view=net-8.0), and never changed (still like that for .NET 8!) The confusion evident in your question about what it means is totally understandable, given `ToDictionary` has nothing to do with "groups"! :)